# Registration and login forms on one page do not work on submit [Symfony]

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony-forms

Trying to login user from a form that is on the same route/page as registration form.

I tried by checking with request->has which form is submitted. But it does not work as intended. If I return specific render inside the else statement I get 'Variable "form" does not exist' when it actually does exist but in the if statement. If I add the variable form inside the else statement after I fill in the input field for username and password I am asked to fill in the input fields of the registration form too.

My controller for registration and login forms(tried a solution for multiple forms found in stackoverflow with if statements):

```
 /**
 * @Route("/",name="home")
 */
public function homeAction(Request $request, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passEncoder, AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils)
{

    $greeting = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(UserGreetings::class)->randomGreet();
    $user = new User();
    $error = null;
    $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);
    if($request->request->has('form')) {
        try {
            $form->handleRequest($request);
            if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
                $encryptedPassword = $passEncoder->encodePassword($user, $user->getPassword());
                $user->setPassword($encryptedPassword);
                $user->setIsActive();
                $user->setRoles();
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $em->persist($user);
                $em->flush();
                $this->addFlash('message', 'You registered successfully! Now you can login. :)');
                return $this->redirectToRoute('home');

            }
        } catch (\Exception $exc) {
            $error = 'Error in adding user: ' . $exc->getCode() . ' ' . $exc->getMessage();
        }
        return $this->render('default/home.html.twig',
            ['form' => $form->createView(), 'error' => $error, 'greeting' => $greeting]);
    } else {
        $authError = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

        $userNameLast = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();
        return $this->render('default/home.html.twig',
            ['form' => $form->createView(), 'error' => $error, 'greeting' => $greeting, 'name' => $userNameLast, 'errorLog' => $authError]);
    }


    return $this->render('default/home.html.twig',
        ['form' => $form->createView(), 'error' => $error, 'greeting' => $greeting, 'name' => $userNameLast, 'errorLog' => $authError]);
}
```

My template:

```
 {% block body %}



<div class="card card-body" id="regged">
    {{ form_start(form) }}
    <legend class="m-b-1 text-sm-center">Register</legend>
    <div class="form-group input-group">
        {{ form_widget(form.email, {'id': 'mail', 'attr': {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Type here'}}) }}
        <label for="mail" class="form-control-placeholder">Email</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group input-group">
        {{ form_widget(form.username, {'id': 'username', 'attr': {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Type here'}}) }}
        <label for="username" class="form-control-placeholder">Username</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group input-group">
        {{ form_widget(form.password.pass, {'id': "passwordFirst", 'attr': {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Password'}}) }}
        <label for="passwordFirst" class="form-control-placeholder">First</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group input-group">
        {{ form_widget(form.password.conf, {'id': "passwordConf", 'attr': {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Password'}}) }}
        <label for="passwordConf" class="form-control-placeholder">Confirm</label>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center">
    {{ form_row(form.Signup, {'attr':{'class': 'btn btn-success btn-sm'}}) }}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="card card-body" id="loged">
    {% if errorLog %}
        <p>
            {{ errorLog.messageKey|trans(errorLog.messageData, 'security') }}
        </p>
    {% endif %}
    <form action="{{ path('home') }}" method="post">
        <p>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" placeholder="username..." value="{{ name }}"><br/><br/>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" placeholder="password...">
            <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="{{ path('profile') }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="">
        </p>
        <button type="submit">Sign in</button>

    </form>
</div>

{% for message in app.flashes('message') %}
<div class="alert alert-success" id="reg_mess">
    {{ message }}
</div>
{% endfor %}

<div id="mes">
<div class="card card-header"></div>
<div class="card card-body">
    {% for greet in greeting %}
    {{ greet.greetingText }}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
</div>





{% endblock %}
```

I want to be able to submit login form or registration form on click on the form's submit button. Right now if I try to register new user, nothing happens also when login form is filled, the front-end security wants the registration form to be filled too.

Comment: You are making this too complicated.  Just use two forms with different post actions.  One to register and one to log in.

Answer (score 0):

You can send action to login_check.

```
  <form action="{{ path('home') }}" method="post">
        <p>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" placeholder="username..." value="{{ name }}"><br/><br/>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" placeholder="password...">
            <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="{{ path('profile') }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="">
        </p>
        <button type="submit">Sign in</button>

    </form>
```

and you can handle registration on homeAction